# How to check checkbox in ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a html table which is binding using Angularjs.Now i want to select checkbox  during ng-repeat with a condition.

```
<tbody>
                            <tr class="gradeX" ng-repeat="itm in usersList">

                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox"/></td>
                                <td> {{itm.FirstName}}</td>

                                <td>{{itm.Email}}</td>

                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
```

I have another field itm.checkstatus.i want to check the checkbox during ng-repeat when itm.checkstatus=1 then checkbox will check else checkbox will not check.how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-checked for this:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked

```
 <tbody>
      <tr class="gradeX" ng-repeat="itm in usersList">
         <td><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="itm.checkstatus == 1" /></td>
         <td>{{itm.FirstName}}</td>
         <td>{{itm.Email}}</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: thanks but i cant understand from this link.can you write this code for me

Comment: Thanks for help. i have used ng-checked="{{itm.checkstatus==1}}".and it is working fine.

Comment: The curly braces shouldn't be necessary